# Scikit-learn 0.15.2 - OneVsRestClassifier not works due to predict_proba not available

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, classification, document-classification

I am trying to do onevsrest classification like below:

```
classifier = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf')))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y)

predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

And I get the error 'predict_proba is not available when probability = false'. I saw that there was a bug reported, the one below:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1946

And it was closed as fixed, so I killed scikit-learn from my Windows PC and completely re-downloaded scikit-learn to have version 0.15.2. But I still get this error. Any suggestions? Or I understood this wrong, and I still can't use SVC with OneVSRestClassifier unless I specify probability=true?

UPDATE: just to clarify, I am trying to actually achieve multi-label classification, here is data source:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fileIn, header = 0, encoding='utf-8-sig')
rows = random.sample(df.index, int(len(df) * 0.9))

work = df.ix[rows]

work_test = df.drop(rows)

X_train = []

y_train = []

X_test = []

y_test = []
for i in work[[i for i in list(work.columns.values) if i.startswith('Change')]].values:
    X_train.append(','.join(i.T.tolist()))

X_train = np.array(X_train)

for i in work[[i for i in list(work.columns.values) if i.startswith('Corax')]].values:
    y_train.append(list(i))


for i in work_test[[i for i in list(work_test.columns.values) if i.startswith('Change')]].values:
    X_test.append(','.join(i.T.tolist()))

X_test = np.array(X_test)

for i in work_test[[i for i in list(work_test.columns.values) if i.startswith('Corax')]].values:
    y_test.append(list(i))


lb = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()

Y = lb.fit_transform(y_train)
```

And after that I send it to pipeline mentioned earlier

Comment: Works fine on my box (scikit-learn current master). Are you sure you're not importing an old version? `python -c 'import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)`.

Comment: It says: 0.15.2. Is it possible that the issue is caused by the fact that use binaries from here (it is suggested on sklearn web-site, but they are still unofficial): http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn. Probably they are not built correctly. Should I just pull everything from sklearn's github page and replace all of my local files?

Comment: Update - I tried to use pip to refresh scikit-learn, but it says: D:\Apps\Python\Scripts>pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in d:\apps\python\lib\site-packages

Cleaning up...

Comment: Even more funny - I have completely killed python from my PC along with all packages files. Than I installed python 3.4, re-downloaded all prerequisites and installed sklearn using pip. Even after that I still get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to dig through code, as I see it tries to call decision_function(self, X) first, and if it results in NotImplementerError it tries predict_proba. So I went to look for base.py in SVM to look for decision_function. I see that it has this: if self._sparse:
            raise NotImplementedError("Decision_function not supported for"
                                      " sparse SVM."). So maybe this is the issue? I am not sure, but maybe the workflow I used results in sparse matrix.

Comment: Though previous comment might be disregarded, since sklearn manual says that SVC could be used with sparse matrix if it was trained on sparse data. And since I use pipeline I am definitely predicting using same representation as I used for training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I did some investigation in code. OneVsRestClassifier tries to call decision_function first and if it fails - it goes for predict_proba function of base classifier (svm.svc in our case).

As far as I see, my X_test is numpy.array of lists of strings. After it undergoes a sequence of transformations specified in pipeline CountVectorizer -> TfidfTransformer it becomes a sparse matrix (by design of these things). As I see currently decision_function is not available for sparse matrices, and there is even an open suggestion on github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/73

So, to summarize, looks like you can't make a multilabel classification using svm.svc unless you specify probability=True. If you do this you introduce some overhead to the classifier.fit process but it will work.

Comment: I can't check it right now, but I will check it tomorrow, and post update here :)

Comment: Ok, it works (though introduces some significant overhead). Updated answer.

Comment: Hmmm, I just noticed that it works terrible. When I send different examples to trained classifier it makes SAME PREDICTIONS for each example.

Comment: BTW, I checked it with different kernels (linear, rbf etc) - each of them with probablility=True starts to output same predictions for each of examples I feed to them during predict operation. Looks like it just outputs the label with the highest probabilities.

Comment: I can't really comment on that without seeing your data and settings. SVM classifiers need extensive tuning to work well, so this may as well be a flaw in your code as in the library.

Comment: Whole code is right above, there are no extra steps. I am not sure how I could post the source data here, but in general it is just a csv file which is read on first step into pandas dataframe. csv has 6 columns with names starting with 'corax' - those are threated y_train and y_test. Rest of columns have names starting with 'change' and they are threated as x_train and x_test.

Comment: Actually I tried to use SVC(kernel='linear', probablility=True) as classifier, it outputs completely different results (compared to just LinearSVC classifier) and it also has same problem - it outputs absolutely same predictions for each example. Other observation is that if LinearSVC outputs something like 4-10 labels per example the simple SVC with linear kernel and probablility=True outputs 50 labels for each example.